# Javascript functional logic not working

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create an object with

> currency
>
> opening balance
>
> and closing balance

i have the following data

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var accounts=[
    {
      "id":"20",
      "name":"OASIS MALL-RMB Account",
      "branchId":"6",
      "type_id":"1",
      "currency_id":"1",
      "balance":"0",
      "createdBy":"2",
      "active":"1",
      "ts":"2017-06-30 00:12:08"
    },
    {
      "id":"21",
      "name":"OASIS MALL-USD Account",
      "branchId":"6",
      "type_id":"1",
      "currency_id":"2",
      "balance":"0",
      "createdBy":"2",
      "active":"1",
      "ts":"2017-06-30 00:12:09"
    },
    {
      "id":"22","name":"OASIS MALL-DIRHAM Account",
      "branchId":"6",
      "type_id":"1",
      "currency_id":"3",
      "balance":"0",
      "createdBy":"2",
      "active":"1",
      "ts":"2017-06-30 00:12:09"
    },
    {
      "id":"23",
      "name":"OASIS MALL-UGX Account",
      "branchId":"6",
      "type_id":"1",
      "currency_id":"4",
      "balance":"0",
      "createdBy":"2",
      "active":"1",
      "ts":"2017-06-30 00:12:09"
    },
    {
      "id":"24",
      "name":"OASIS MALL-KSH Account",
      "branchId":"6",
      "type_id":"1",
      "currency_id":"5",
      "balance":"0",
      "createdBy":"2",
      "active":"1",
      "ts":"2017-06-30 00:12:09"
    }
]

var balances =[
  {
    "id":"101",
    "branchId":"6",
    "accountId":"20",
    "openingBalance":"3260000",
    "closingBalance":"3260000",
    "date":"2017-08-15",
    "ts":"2017-08-15 02:27:08"
  },
  {
    "id":"102",
    "branchId":"6",
    "accountId":"21",
    "openingBalance":"1882492",
    "closingBalance":"1882492",
    "date":"2017-08-15",
    "ts":"2017-08-15 02:27:08"
  },
  {
    "id":"103","branchId":"6",
    "accountId":"22",
    "openingBalance":"-3000",
    "closingBalance":"-3000",
    "date":"2017-08-15",
    "ts":"2017-08-15 02:27:08"
  },
  {
    "id":"104",
    "branchId":"6",
    "accountId":"23",
    "openingBalance":"95199318",
    "closingBalance":"95199318",
    "date":"2017-08-15",
    "ts":"2017-08-15 02:27:08"
  },
  {
    "id":"105",
    "branchId":"6",
    "accountId":"24",
    "openingBalance":"1847000",
    "closingBalance":"1847000",
    "date":"2017-08-15",
    "ts":"2017-08-15 02:27:08"
  }
]
```

I know how to do it in loops and if statements. But i want to do it the functional way
I have tried writing this code.

```
var DisplayAccounts = function(accounts,balances){

  var displayaccounts = _(accounts).map((x)=>{


      var mybalance = _(balances)
      .reduce((acc,z)=>{
         acc={
           currency :x.currency_id,
           openingBalance : z.openingBalance,
           closingBalance : z.closingBalance
         };
         return acc;
      },{});
     return mybalance;

  });
  return  displayaccounts;
}

console.log(DisplayAccounts(accounts,balances));
```

but it gives me an answer that i dont like.
IT gives me

```
[ { currency: '1',
    openingBalance: '1847000',
    closingBalance: '1847000' },
  { currency: '2',
    openingBalance: '1847000',
    closingBalance: '1847000' },
  { currency: '3',
    openingBalance: '1847000',
    closingBalance: '1847000' },
  { currency: '4',
    openingBalance: '1847000',
    closingBalance: '1847000' },
  { currency: '5',
    openingBalance: '1847000',
    closingBalance: '1847000' } ]
```

the same opening and closing balances throught. I need each currency is with its corresponding opening and closing balances like this .

```
[ { currency: '1',
    openingBalance: '3260000',
    closingBalance: '3260000' },
  { currency: '2',
    openingBalance: '1882492',
    closingBalance: '1882492' },
  { currency: '3',
    openingBalance: '-3000',
    closingBalance: '-3000' },
  { currency: '4',
    openingBalance: '95199318',
    closingBalance: '95199318' },
  { currency: '5',
    openingBalance: '1847000',
    closingBalance: '1847000' } ]
```

How can it do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a pure functional approach but generates the desired result:

```
function displayAccounts(acc, bal) {
    return acc.map(x => {
        let b = bal.find(b => b.accountId === x.id);
        return {
            currency: x.currency_id,
            openingBalance: b.openingBalance,
            closingBalance: b.closingBalance
        }
    });
}

console.log(displayAccounts(accounts, balances));
```

Comment: Thank you. If some one gave me a purely functional answer i will rate it and accept it

Comment: But wait @DevDig This seems like a pure function to me. Can you tell me why its not pure ?

Comment: @HenryBbosa Since functional programming is a paradigm, some might consider this as functional. Some purists may however define functional programming as 'composing pure functions', so there would not be a 'state' in the accounts map function (the b variable).